# AngularJS: how to get the error status of $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my scenario:

My controller is like:

```
var userData = $http(
{
     method: "post",
     url: "http://some-domain.com/t-app/mobile-data/login.php",
     data    : $scope.loginForm, //forms user object
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
userData.success(function (userdataobject)
{
    $rootScope.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];
});
```

I know this will only work if the internet connection is available. My question is that, in this scenario, how do I know the error status like "404" or if internet connection is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `status` field (from [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)):

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(
    function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    },
    function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        if (response.status === 404)
        {
            //your code here
        }
});
```

In your case it's:

```
$http(
{
   method: "post",
   url: "http://some-domain.com/t-app/mobile-data/login.php",
   data    : $scope.loginForm, //forms user object
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
.then(
  function(response) {
    $rootScope.status_id = userdataobject.data["status_id"];
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response.status === 404) {
        //your code here
    }
  } 
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. So you are suggesting me to use 

`var userData = $http(
{
     method: "post",
     url: "http://some-domain.com/t-app/mobile-data/login.php",
     data    : $scope.loginForm, //forms user object
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
userData.success(function (userdataobject)
{
    $rootScope.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];
});
userData.errorCallback(response) 
{
    if (response.status === 404)
        {
            //your code here
        }
});
`
is this fine or should i need to change it again?

Comment: I'd suggest you not to use `success`, `error` as they are deprecated. see the update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. Please checkout this [snapshot](http://prntscr.com/9k8g9m) no error response :( 
i'm using this code: [snapshoot](http://prntscr.com/9k8h6v) 
`var userData = $http(
{
method: "post",
url: "http://somedomain.com/mobile-data/update-tasks.php",
data: $scope.loginForm, //forms user object
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
userData.then(function(response) {
 $rootScope.status_id = userdataobject.data["status_id"];
 },
  function(response) {
 console.error(response);
   if (response.status === 404) {
   //your code here
  }
 } 
);

Comment: After so many research i'm only getting one error status that is '0'. haha.. Now in any documentation i can't get the table of error codes :( Can you please help me regarding this? And btw thanks alot for your support.

Comment: @TechKid, that's very strange. Does your request reach server? What's in browser's `Network` tab in developer tools?

Comment: I'm using mozila, with firebug.

Comment: My Friend is there any way that I can repeatly call a function in angularjs. i'm using this `$interval( $rootScope.synchronization(), 1000 );` but it only call once the synchronization function.

Answer (score 1):

In relation with your example:

```
var userData = $http({
     method: "post",
     url: "http://some-domain.com/t-app/mobile-data/login.php",
     data    : $scope.loginForm, //forms user object
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});

userData.success(function (userdataobject) {
    $rootScope.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];
}).catch(function(errorResponse, status) {
    console.error(errorResponse); //for debugging
    if (errorResponse.status == 404) {
      //Handle 404 error 
    }
    //or if (status == 404) {}
});
```

The `errorResponse` will have these fields:

- data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
- config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still no error response i got :( Here it is snapshot http://prntscr.com/9k8db8 
and this code i used: 
`userData.success(function (userdataobject)
        {
      $rootScope.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];
      $rootScope.message = userdataobject["message"];   
      $location.path("/taskStatus");
 }).catch(function(errorResponse, status) 
 {
 alert(errorResponse);
 console.error(errorResponse); //for debugging
 if (errorResponse.status == 404) 
 {
 alert(errorResponse.status);
  //Handle 404 error 
         }
 //or if (status == 404) {}
});`

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri, i'm only getting one error status that is '0'. haha.. Now after googling i couldn't find the table of error codes :( Can you please help me regarding this? And btw thanks alot for your support.

Comment: @TechKid No problem. A list of statuses: https://github.com/wdavidw/node-http-status/blob/master/lib/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Your code may be like this:

```
$http(
{
     method: "post",
     url: "http://some-domain.com/t-app/mobile-data/login.php",
     data    : $scope.loginForm, //forms user object
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $rootScope.status_id = response["status_id"];
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.error(response.status);
    console.error(response.statusText);
});
```

In this way you controller the success and error

Comment: Thank you @victor, i'm only getting one error status that is '0'. haha.. Now after googling i couldn't find the table of error codes :( Can you please help me regarding this? And btw thanks alot for your support.

Comment: If you got a response code of 0 from XMLHttpRequest can mean that you are being blocked by the same origin policy. Make sure that you are using relative URLs for your AJAX requests.